# Assembly Language Usage

Tags: assembly, q

Assembly is a language I'd like to learn but still you don't hear often that something has been programmed in assembly. My question is what are the uses of assembly language? Is it still used?

Comment: Assembly is a terrible language for programming something that has to be absolutely bug-free, like drivers. Some parts, maybe, but definitely not all of it.

Comment: I really don,t get the utility of that language. Might as well program the whole driver in the other language and not doing some parts with Assembly then..?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Comment: Assembly is a low-level building block. It is used, but you're unlikely to write it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly language can make sense in a number of situations.

1. High volume, minimum cost embedded systems. The extra hardware to run something like C can be prohibitive.
2. Improving efficiency.
3. Access to hardware not possible/available via higher level languages.

2 used to be important, but has shrunk almost into oblivion in the last few decades.

Answer (score 3):

What is assembly used for?

Short answer: everything software-related.

Is it still being used?

Short answer: in it's most pure form, rarely so. Indirectly it's being used in all software.

Longer answer:

Assembly is a way to make raw binary code readable to humans. When the first computers were being built one could simply dial in the instructions to perform a operation, however as computers grew more complex and the need for more advanced computations arose dialing in all the instructions that make up a program in raw binary became tedious, very tedious. Consider a 220 line long program using a 8-bit wide opcode and 16-bit for the operands (and/or registers or memory adresses) this would mean that every instruction is 24-bits, thatś 24 zeroes and ones, long. Multiply this by 220 (the amount of instructions assuming there is one instruction on each line) and you get 5280. This is the amount of zeroes and ones you have to dial in without making a single mistake. Tedious, and error-prone.

Therefore computer scientists came up with the idea to use mnemonics to describe all the different instructions. A example would be the abbreviation 'mov' which in x86 assembly stands for 'move'. It does exactly that, it moves (or actually copies) data from one place to another. This makes it far easier to read and write programs.

Because assembly is merely using words and rules to describe binary code it's ALWAYS the fastest. You are talking directly to the CPU. That's one hell of an advantage.

Still computers grew even more complex and software became more advanced, or rather, bigger. Typing a few lines of assembly is fine but writing, say, a web browser in assembly would be a complete disaster to keep up, there is so much data you need to keep track of and itś easy to make a mistake.

Thus more advanced languages were developed. Languages like C/C++, usually reffered to as high level langauges because they don't talk directly to the CPU. Languages like these often use build in functions, mini-ASM programs designed to do a specific task. One could say that all the high level programming languages are basically a massive library of ASM functions.

Now, python for example was coded in C, C itself calls on assembly and assembly calls on binary code. Basically, the higher we get, the more dissasociated we get from ASM, but itś still ASM at the CORE. The only difference is that we utilize the computers themselves to compile our human-readable 'code' into binary.

I hope this all makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

**Assembly language is used for transforming higher-level programming languages like C into machine code.** Processors can only run machine code -- a sequence of short, discrete, instructions encoded in binary format. Every time *any* program runs, machine code is being executed by a processor. Assembly language is simply a human-readable form of machine code.

The job of transforming high-level code into machine code is performed by a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), and assembly is typically created along the way as an intermediate representation before being translated into machine code. In this light, assembly is written at least as often popular high-level programming languages -- its just written by another program.

**Reasons you might write a program in assembly language**:

- Your professor told you to
- You don't trust a compiler to generate optimized or working machine code
- You're writing your own compiler or programming language

**Common assembly languages (and underlying ISA)**

- [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)
- [SPARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC)
- [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays assembly is mostly used for when the high-level language of choice doesn't grant the programmer access to certain CPU features, such as vector instructions or prefetching.